# Can SIGSEGV caused during a memory read(not write) be ignored?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

Can I ignore SIGSEGV caused because of an invalid read(not write)? I am to catching it using a __try {} / __catch{} block since I am writing it in Windows. I am successfully able to catch it and ignore it. My question mainly is since I am only trying to read the memory and not trying to write anything to it, would the read  cause corruption? Or is it safe?

```
class Object {
int first;
int second;
bool safe;

public:
Object() {
    safe = true;
}

bool isSafe() {
    return safe;
}
```

}

Comment: "Safe" might be relative here. If you were getting an access violation on a write attempt I'd expect the actual write to not have happened (i.e. been blocked by the OS/runtime); ignoring one on a read I likewise wouldn't expect the process state to change per se. However, it does raise the question of exactly how you've got into this situation (dereference null, use-after-free) and whether the rest of the program is "correct"...

Comment: Ii have a flag after every object that I allocate to indicate if it is safe to use. When I try to access the flag at times when I have not allocated memory (only read), I crash. This is what I am trying to save.

Comment: It's tricky to give a definitive recommendation without seeing sample code for your class(es) and usage, but that doesn't sound like the right pattern to use (i.e. it sounds like in an attempt to avoid a problem the same problem is being created again). I would expect to see things like, for example, testing for `nullptr` and/or RAII, but it would depend on the rest of your implementation. Are you able to show sample code?

Comment: Added a sample of the code

Comment: If it's throwing when you call eg. `obj->isSafe()`, then I would expect that `obj` is `nullptr`; if so, that approach doesn't really make sense, as you can't call an instance method without having a live instance. You might instead be wanting to check whether `obj != nullptr` first.

Comment: I might have had somebody freeing the object leaving behind a dangling pointer, that's my usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question comments and the C++11 tag, you have a few approaches available to you here:

1. To `delete` a pointer without setting it to `nullptr` afterwards is not correct; if such code sites are under your control, correct it there. (Note also that if something else calls `delete` against a `nullptr` it is a safe no-op.) This is a little trickier if the pointer gets copied and stored elsewhere, however, which leads to...
2. Possibly consider using some other means of storing these objects, such as instances in a container type (as distinct from via pointers) or, if you have to use pointers, using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` instead if the program design allows the concept of who "owns" the instances to be determined (and you can perform such a change without breaking too many things). If your code accepts a `weak_ptr`, you convert it to a `shared_ptr` via `weak.lock()` for use; if it happens to get passed a `weak_ptr` for which the corresponding `shared_ptr`s elsewhere are all gone (and the underlying instance thus `delete`'d) the result will be zero-equivalent -- so will naturally go down the `else` branch of an `if` statement.
3. If you can't do either #1 or #2, then your try-catch approach from the question may be viable, but do so on attempting to access the object itself; both the fields and instance method will lead to the same access violation if tried on a null pointer, so you might as well remove the code for `isSafe()`. If you do this, your catch handler should execute cleanup code to correct the pointer itself -- the rest of your code may make this tricky depending on how many times the pointer is passed around, however.

If this problem presented in one of our codebases, my preference would be for #2, then #1, with #3 as a last resort.